# WPF call method parent from usercontrol

Tags: c#, wpf, methods, user-controls, parent

I want to call a method from user control in WPF

I´ve a Window with a list and I have a method that get this list.

```
private ObservableCollection<int> _lst;

public MainWindow()
{
     InitializeComponent();

     getList();
    }

public void getList()
{
    _lst = List<int>(); 
}
```

In this page I use a usercontrol:

```
UserControlAAA userControl = new UserControlAAA ();

gridDatos.Children.Add(userControl);
```

I want to do something like this inside of usercontrol:

```
Window win = Window.GetWindow(this);

win.getList();
```

but I can´t call win.getList();

I want to call the method getList from my usercontrol, but I don´t know how to do it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll need to cast the `Window` object to the specific window type you're using - which in your case is `MainWindow`:

```
MainWindow win = (MainWindow)Window.GetWindow(this);
win.getList();
```

However, it's not wise to have such coupling between the user control and the window it's hosted in, since that means you will only be able to use it in a window of type `MainWindow`. It would be better to expose a dependency property in the user control and bind the list to that property - this way the user control will have the data it requires and it will also be reusable in any type of window.

Answer (score 0):

Solution from @Adi Lester is working but it break WPF coding ruler. Proper way of doing this is using event like in the linked answer below
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19384953/3099317